# How to connect Java Applocation to JIRA?

Tags: java, jira, jira-rest-java-api

I want my java application to communicate with JIRA how can i achieve this functinality. I mean what configuratons are need to add, what are jar files etc ?

Comment: A web search for "Java JIRA API" gives this page as the **first** result: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/java-apis/

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need Jar files if your java project is using Maven. Just add maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
    <version>${atlassian.product.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using maven as build system to your project. Download jar from maven directly and add it to your project.

Follow the documentation https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/java-apis/ and start development